# Change Property on click angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I want to change a radio button's property on a click on a `<div>`.
In the below code, the div has a class and I have to change the radio button's property to true if the div is clicked.
I wrote this event handling using jQuery.

Can you tell me how to solve this using Angularjs?

```js
   var app = angular.module('myapp', []);

 app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
//How to write code here in Angular//
 });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app='myapp'>

  <head>
    <script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="2.1.4" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.8" data-semver="1.4.8" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" >
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div>
    <input ng-click="Large()" id="large" type="radio" name="button">Large
    <input ng-click="Medium()" id="medium" type="radio" name="button">medium
    <input ng-click="Small()" id="small" type="radio" name="button">Small
</div>
<div>
<div class="col-xs-12 field">first //click</div><br/>
<div class="col-xs-6 field">second //click</div><br/>
<div class="col-xs-4 field">third //click</div>
</div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
 $('.field').bind('click', function () {
        if ($(this).hasClass('col-xs-12')) {
            $('#large').prop("checked", true);;
        }
        else if ($(this).hasClass('col-xs-6')) {
            $('#medium').prop("checked", true);
        }
        else
            $('#small').prop("checked", true);
        
    })

});
</script>
    </body>
  </html>
```

(also available at https://plnkr.co/edit/PNabPp2OvYAS76p3KfsH?p=preview)

Comment: @ArunPJohny because i have different type of DATA on that div,, that is why i am not going to use LABEL ..

Answer (score 2):

Since you can't use `label`, the angular solution will be is to use `model` values

```js
var app = angular.module('myapp', [], function() {})

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.fieldClicked = function(size) {
    if (size == 'col-xs-12') {
      $scope.size = 'large';
    } else if (size == 'col-xs-6') {
      $scope.size = 'medium';
    } else if (size == 'col-xs-4') {
      $scope.size = 'small';
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myapp">
  <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div>
      <input ng-model="size" value="large" type="radio" name="button">Large
      <input ng-model="size" value="medium" type="radio" name="button">medium
      <input ng-model="size" value="small" type="radio" name="button">Small
    </div>
    <div>
      <!--ng-click="fieldClicked(div.size)" in template-->
      <div class="col-xs-12 field" ng-click="fieldClicked('col-xs-12')">first</div>
      <br/>
      <div class="col-xs-6 field" ng-click="fieldClicked('col-xs-6')">second</div>
      <br/>
      <div class="col-xs-4 field" ng-click="fieldClicked('col-xs-4')">third</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: that's ok,, but how can we add that property dynamically... means those classes will change dynamically... means if i set those 3divs to 'col-xs-6' have to show exact property at radio buttons.. that is why i wrote in jquery to understand, can u pls write the code in angular like i have written jquery ..

Comment: @VijjuSena so you don't know upfront what class is used for the div?

Comment: those classes will be changed with this expressions {{div.size}} ..

Comment: but the allowed values are 4/6 and 12, is that right?

Comment: @VijjuSena see the update

Comment: sry,, first button should not be 'col-xs-12'... that class will be changed dynamically that div might be 'col-xs-6 or col-xs-4'.. we con't find that what would be in that class...

Comment: what ever it would be in that class ,, if it would be 'col-xs-12' have to be checked Large radio button, if it would be 'col-xs-6' have to be checked 'medium' like that

Answer (score 2):

> Update the `model` value using `ng-click` directive

Try this:

```js
var app = angular.module('myapp', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.val = ''
  $scope.clickHadler = function(val) {
    $scope.val = val;
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app='myapp' ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div>
    <input ng-click="Large()" ng-model='val' value='first' id="large" type="radio" name="button">Large
    <input ng-click="Medium()" ng-model='val' value='second' id="medium" type="radio" name="button">medium
    <input ng-click="Small()" ng-model='val' value='third' id="small" type="radio" name="button">Small
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="col-xs-12" ng-click='clickHadler("first")'>first //click</div>
    <br/>
    <div class="col-xs-6" ng-click='clickHadler("second")'>second //click</div>
    <br/>
    <div class="col-xs-4" ng-click='clickHadler("third")'>third //click</div>
  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: that's ok,, but how can we add that property dynamically... means those classes will change dynamically... means if i set those 3divs to 'col-xs-6' have to show exact property at radio buttons.. that is why i wrote in jquery to understand, can u pls write the code in angular like i have written jquery ..

Comment: _Dynamically_ refers to `ng-repeat` right ? If yes, then what is the issue ? Both, the check boxes and respective divs will be created under `ng-repeat`..

Comment: no i did not use ng-repeat .. those divs appended dynamically.. then classes will be added by click on that radio button on selected div,,

Comment: I do not think mixing angular with `jQuery` is gonna help! All the best!

Answer (score 0):

No need of script here, just use `label` instead of `div`

```js
var app = angular.module('myapp', [], function() {})

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

})
```

```html
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myapp">
  <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div>
      <input ng-click="Large()" id="large" type="radio" name="button">Large
      <input ng-click="Medium()" id="medium" type="radio" name="button">medium
      <input ng-click="Small()" id="small" type="radio" name="button">Small
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="large" class="col-xs-12 field">first</label>
      <br/>
      <label for="medium" class="col-xs-6 field">second</label>
      <br/>
      <label for="small" class="col-xs-4 field">third</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what ever it would be in that class ,, if it would be 'col-xs-12' have to be checked Large radio button, if it would be 'col-xs-6' have to be checked 'medium' like that